# Stuck on "Bootloader is unlocked" screen, can't boot into recovery

Tags: adb, rooting, recovery-mode, twrp, bootloader

So I wanted to root my OnePlus 6 after updating to **android 10**
(OnePlus6Oxygen_22_OTA_041_all_1911142043_dde113e5 3cd0f9.zip)

I tried booting into twrp via fastboot using `fastboot flash boot twrp.img`
(twrp-3.3.1-x_blu_spark_v9.101_op6.img, **my bootloader is unlocked**).

I then tried rebooting directly into twrp, but now it's just **stuck on the "Bootloader is unlocked" screen.**

I can still boot into fastboot, but I can't boot into recovery or reboot normally since it just gets stuck on the bootloader unlocked screen.

**Please Help!**

Edit1: Changing my boot slot from *b* to *a* gives me access to the stock recovery. not sure where to go from here though.

Edit2: Fortunately, [ManikandanGuru over at xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-6/how-to/patched-boot-image-magisk-16-7-beta-t3818853/) had uploaded the stock boot.img, which works perfectly.

Comment: the above fastboot command does flash twrp recovery permanently into boot partition, you can't reboot normally because boot.img is gone